# smoothing curve in an array in c#.net

Tags: c#, zedgraph, aforge

I have an array of int and I plot that values in a graph. (using zedgraphcontrol)

In that curve I want to find local maxima using C#.net
My idea is smoothing the curve to remove the noices. 
How can I find that places.

many thanks for all of your replies

Comment: Well what kind of model is it?  Is it a linear regression?  Is it parabolic?  Exponential?  Also, I assume by noice you mean noise by which you mean outliers.  There's no standard definition for outliers, so you have to give us a bit more context of your data, its range, and its calculation.  Furthermore, what have you tried so far in dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I won't attempt to address the points Oleksii addresses in his answer, however I will show a simple example of how to smooth a curve in ZedGraph:

```
GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

LineItem myLine = myPane.CurveList.AddCurve("Data", myPointPairList, Color.Blue);

myLine.Line.IsSmooth = true;
myLine.Line.SmoothTension = 0.1F;
```

Values from 0.0F to 1.0F affect the smoothing amount, >1.0F is likely undesirable.

Source code documentation for smoothing: http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_Line_IsSmooth.htm

Zedgraph References:

- Introduction and examples: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx
- Source code documentation: http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/default.html

Comment: This doesn't remove noise, it makes it worse, because it doesn't downsample anything.  If anything it increases the amount of points.
But this was still a cool feature, maybe after downsampling then applying this it would work.  +1 for learning something.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the context. If you only need to find local maximum, then you can just have an interval (sub-array) and do simple iterative `Math.Max()`. This is, however, may not be what you want.

As you also mentioned smoothing, which is different from finding local maximum. There are [many techniques](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=smoothing%20of%20a%20signal) you can use for that, which are based on area, signal type, time, frequency, space, phase, your needs, your goals, your hypothesis etc.

You can start with some exploratory statistics on the signal to help you in understanding which technique you can apply. Such tools are available in stats packages (e.g. SPSS, Minitab) and Matlab. Take a look at the signal plots, try curve fitting and maybe linear regression first. From there you can see where to go.